# Chef if statement is broken

Tags: chef-infra

I have a simple chef cookbook that is supposed to chef if a file exists. If it does exist, it should terminate, if not , move on to the next recipe:

```
file '/tmp/db_backup.lock' do
    action :nothing
    only_if { ::File.exist?('/tmp/db_backup.lock') }
    raise "backup in progress since"
    not_if { ::File.exist?('/tmp/db_backup.lock') }
    include_recipe "#{cookbook_name}::hostname"
end
```

However, when i run this code against the server, it always fails out and prints out the raise statement. Can anyone suggest might be the issue with this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `raise` statement in the middle of a resource like that is going to *always* fail and output your raise statement during the Chef [compile phase](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html#the-chef-client-run). In addition you can't run an `include_recipe` inside another resource like that. Lastly, you should not have multiple guards and in this case those guards are conflicting. One tells the resource to not run if the file exist and the other tells it to run only if it exists. What you need to do is something like this:

```
if ::File.exist?('/tmp/db_backup.lock')
  raise 'backup in progress, stopping'
else
  include_recipe "${cookbook_name::hostname}"
end
```

This will raise the exception if the file exists otherwise it will run the included recipe.

Or, if you would like to just skip the included recipe but continue the Chef run you can do something like:

```
if ::File.exist?('/tmp/db_backup.lock')
  Chef::Log.warn("backup in progress, skipping #{cookbook_name::hostname}")
else
  include_recipe "#{cookbook_name::hostname}"
end
```